# Silverlight Image Display - Potential implementations?

Tags: silverlight, image-manipulation

Currently I have a silverlight business application (C# Hosted in ASP.Net on IIS). The database behind the app is setup with a one to many relationship between two particular tables - One Job, Many Images. So for each job I display In my application I have potentially a large number of images to display.

Currently I use a listbox which get populated with the images that are parsed from uri's stored in the database table. Each image has a datetime stamp on it.
 What I would like to do would be to display the most recent image as a thumbnail with the ability to click and zoom into it, whilst having all the other images in some sort of condensed scrollbar.

I've spent a lot of time looking round and have seen a huge number of rubbish implementations, either pertaining to be non-business like or just way to over the top. Could anyone suggest some options to me for this particular situation?

Comment: Details of the platform you are running on your server and the language you are using there would be helpful

Comment: Have ammended the question appropriately...